# Issues with Deleting rows when using a custom class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios9

I am currently trying to code a table row deletion (from Core Data). I am using a custom class called "CustomTableViewCell". Everything was working OK until I implemented a snippet from a previous app which basically just add the swipe to delete feature. I am now getting the following error:

Cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewCell' to expected argument type 'CustomTableViewCell'

The offending code is as it follows:

---

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject) // THIS IS THE OFFENDING CASE
    case .Move:
        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}
```

---

The method is pretty simple: I believe it's the one used in the Master Detail template. The difference is the custom class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)` is returning a `UITableViewCell`.  You probably need to cast that into your custom type with `as! CustomTableViewCell` before you pass it to your method.

Comment: It already is:    `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)
        return cell
    }`

Comment: In the update line above where you are getting the error, I mean

Comment: Duh. Fixed. The issue was actually on the offending line: `self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as! CustomTableViewCell Custom, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject) // THIS IS THE OFFENDING CASE`